# IntelliJ file reference file not found

Tags: intellij-idea

I have been using IntelliJ Idea for a while now, but I have always had a problem with the following:

`Show Intention Actions (or Option + Enter) > Inject Language/Reference > File Reference`

Whenever I try to use this, it acts like the root directory is the same directory as the Java class. However, the way I have IntelliJ set up is so the root directory for the program is the project directory.

This means that whenever I try to inject a file reference, I can not get the file completion, and I get an error but the code still compiles.

How can I make the file reference feature use the project root for its base directory?